# How to inject an interface that inherits from another interface that has an implementation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have an interface and implementation in the infrastructure package in my application.
In the domain layer, I want to access this interface with another interface that inherits from the infrastructure interface. but Spring cannot recognize the corresponding bean for this interface

**Infrastructure package**

```
    interface PushNotificationService {
       fun push(): Mono<Void>
    }
    
    @Service
    class PushNotificationServiceImpl() : PushNotificationService {
        override fun send(): Mono<Void> {
            //Call grpc to push notification
        }
    }
```

**Domain package**

```
    //import PushNotificationService from the infrastructure package
    
    interface PushNotificationService: PushNotificationService
    
    @Service
    class MessengerServiceImpl(
        @Autowired val pushNotificationService: PushNotificationService //I want to use the interface defined in my domain layer
    )
```

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: No you can't because your PushNotificationService has no implementation!

Comment: You should move the interface to domain module, as domain should not depend on infrastructure.